# Android transparent area click

Tags: android, android-activity

Situation: i have this button (image 1) that launches the activity (image 2).

Question: how can i make it to where when the user clicks the background (transparent) on the second image it will go back to the first screen?

[image]

[image]

class with button:
            package com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning;

```
    import com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.R;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }         

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null);

            ImageButton connect = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebooklogin);
            connect.setOnClickListener(this);


            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new FacebookActivity();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), FacebookActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

DialogFragment :
        package com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning;

```
import com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class FacebookActivity extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login, null))

        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // sign in the user ...
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       FacebookActivity.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });      
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

EDIT logcat:

```
    05-17 18:28:21.224: W/dalvikvm(27699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050038 (com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning:id/fragment_container) for fragment FacebookActivity{40cd27e8 #2 id=0x7f050038}
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    05-17 18:28:21.245: E/AndroidRuntime(27699):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-17 18:28:23.764: E/Trace(27715): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

EDIT XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#3B5998"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                        <!-- Facebook logo -->
                         <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/facebooklogo3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblEmail"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtEmail"
                            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_logo" />

                         <!-- Email inforamtion -->
                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEmail"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblPassword"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/facebooklogo3"
                            android:text="Email:"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblEmail"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/lblEmail"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                        <!-- Passworld informaiton -->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblPassword"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Password:"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblPassword"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/lblPassword"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textPassword" 
                            android:padding="2dp"/>

                        <!-- Save -->

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/signup"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Need an account? \n Sign up using your phone"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/savelogin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:text="Save Login"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

manafest:

```
    <activity android:name=".FacebookActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the second screen as `Dialog` and then call `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` which will close the dialog if you touch the screen outside of the dialog.

Comment: Well that sounds reasonable, how would i implement an XML as a dialog?

Comment: It's recomended to use `DialogFragment` to implement Dialog behaviour in Android now. So if you are planning to follow the good practices - read this - [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
The quick solution:
 `LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
 dialog.show();`

Comment: Ok i've done my best to use the best practices, but its crashing on load.

Comment: In method call `transaction.replace(0, newFragment);` you must provide container id specified in your xml file. Container is the place where your fragment will be placed. Example: 
`<RelativeLayout                    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout     
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>`
Method call: `transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do as makovkastar stated, or a less desirable solution would be to override the activities' default onTouch method and detect where the user is pressing. If it's outside of the bounds of the box, sent it's visibility property to `View.GONE`